# I'm trying to make randomly generated particles in my 2D javascript game

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game on code.org and its a 2D game. I want to make randomly generated rects on the canvas. I have this outside of the draw loop to declare the variables:

```
var xvar = []; 
var t;
for(var sand1 = 0; sand1<=100; sand1++){
  t[xvar] = randomNumber(0,200);
  tx++;
}
```

and this in the draw loop to draw the rects using the newly generated variable with a random number:

```
for(var sand = 0; sand<=100; sand++){
    rect(t[xvar], t[xvar], 3,3);
}
```

But it gives me this error when I try to run it:

> ERROR: Line: 57: TypeError: Cannot set property '' of undefined

Basically what I'm trying to make is 100 3x3 rectangles on my canvas but I want them to stay in one place the entire time.

Comment: You didn't set `t` to anything.  It's undefined.  `tx` is also undefined.

Comment: which is line 57?

Comment: Line 57:    t[xvar] = randomNumber(0,200);

Comment: I don't think you can use an array (`xvar`) as an index for an array/object.  Why is `xvar` an array and why is `t` not set to anything?  Also, what's `tx`?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems.

```
var t = [];
for (var sand1 = 0; sand1 <= 100; sand1++){
    t[sand1]=Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1); 
};
var d = document.getElementById('show-numbers');
for (var showme = 0; showme <= 100; showme++){
    d.innerHTML += t[showme] + ', </br>';
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vozrrt2j/1/

You need to study up here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array